# How would I assign n number of properties to an object depending on the given parameters in a function?

Tags: javascript, object, createelement

I am making a more simple way of `document.createElement` function, and this is what I have so far.

```
function createEl(type, parent) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to make it so that I can add use the `argumments`, and using the parameter, you can assign any number of properties to the `element` object I have created inside the function. For example, if you wanted to add one that determined `element`'s `absolute` style. I'm thinking it should have to do `Object.assign`, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass objects, one for attributes and one for style:

```
function createEl(type, parent, attributes, style) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    //add attributes
    Object.entries(attributes).forEach(([attributeName, attributeValue]) => {
        element.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    });
    //add style 
    Object.entries(style).forEach(([styleProp, styleValue]) => {
        console.log(styleProp+ styleValue);
        element.style[styleProp] = styleValue;
    });
    domElement = document.getElementById(parent);
    domElement.appendChild(element);
}
```

and call the function with:

```
    const type = "div";
    const parent = "test";
    const attributes = {"id" : "div1" , "class" : "redButton", "..." : "..."};
    const style = {"position" : "absolute", "color" : "green" , "..." : "..."};
    createEl(type, parent, attributes, style);
```

You can set any sort of attriubutes and style properties

Answer (score 1):

if i understynd right, you mean something like

```
function createEl(type, parent, optional = {}) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    if(optional.sample.lenth)
    {
        // do something with optional.sample
    }
    if(optional.foo.lenth)
    {
        // do something with optional.foo
    }
    parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

so you can call it without the third param `createEl('div','div#id')` or with an object `createEl('div','div#id',{param:2,foo:'bar'})`

Comment: Hm. How does that work? Also, is there any way optional could be written without the = {}? Because I'm using Khan Academy webpages, and that's not allowed.

Comment: try to use `option = new object()` and maybe using [] like arrays, try read something about objects or arrays in js [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'm still not understanding this a lot, so I'm giving encouragement, but there was another answer that I was looking for a bit more. But still, thanks a lot!